# .net is saving my programmatically created bitmap incorrectly

Tags: c#, .net, bmp

I have some code that creates a 1*1000 px gradient and saves it as a bmp.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int height = 1000;
    int value1 = 249;
    int value2 = 227;

    string folder = "C:\\Users\\TehSuckerer\\Desktop\\Gradient\\";

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1, height);

    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        int value = Dither1D(Lerp(value1, value2, (float)i / height), i);
        bitmap.SetPixel(0, i, Color.FromArgb(value, value, value));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(bitmap.GetPixel(0, i).ToString());
    }

    if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

    try
    {
        bitmap.Save(folder + "Gradient.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

static float Lerp (int value1, int value2, float lerp)
{
    return (1 - lerp) * value1 + lerp * value2;
}

static float SineEaseOut (int value1, int value2, float lerp)
{
    return Lerp(value1, value2, (float)Math.Sin(lerp * Math.PI / 2));
}

static int Dither1D (float value, int coord)
{
    float remainder = value % 1;
    if (remainder < 0.25 || (remainder < 0.75 && (coord % 2 == 0)))
        return (int)Math.Floor(value);
    return (int)Math.Ceiling(value);
}
```

As you can see, I write all the color values into the log just before I save the bmp, to be sure.
They look good, the last 20 values are

```
(...)  
Color [A=255, R=227, G=227, B=227]  
Color [A=255, R=228, G=228, B=228]  
Color [A=255, R=227, G=227, B=227]  
Color [A=255, R=228, G=228, B=228]  
Color [A=255, R=227, G=227, B=227]  
Color [A=255, R=228, G=228, B=228]  
Color [A=255, R=227, G=227, B=227]  
Color [A=255, R=228, G=228, B=228]  
Color [A=255, R=227, G=227, B=227]  
Color [A=255, R=227, G=227, B=227]  
Color [A=255, R=227, G=227, B=227]  
Color [A=255, R=227, G=227, B=227]  
Color [A=255, R=227, G=227, B=227]  
Color [A=255, R=227, G=227, B=227]  
Color [A=255, R=227, G=227, B=227]  
Color [A=255, R=227, G=227, B=227]  
Color [A=255, R=227, G=227, B=227]  
Color [A=255, R=227, G=227, B=227]  
Color [A=255, R=227, G=227, B=227]  
Color [A=255, R=227, G=227, B=227]
```

In other words, there is some part that is dithered between 227 and 228, which is what I want.
However, when I save the file and open it in Photoshop, it looks nothing like that. Here, the last 20 values are

```
(...)  
228  
228  
228  
228  
227  
228  
228  
228  
227  
227  
227  
227  
227  
227  
227  
227  
227  
227  
227  
227
```

I just don't understand what is happening here. How can I make .net save the image correctly?

Comment: If you open the image again in code and print out the pixels do they match .net or photoshop?

Comment: Have you switched off colour management in Photoshop for that image?

Comment: @FloatingKiwi Good idea. When I reopen the file in code, the values seem to be correct. But when rendered in Photoshop, they are wrong...

Comment: @Andrew Morton Color management is off. But even if it were on, I don't understand, why it would change only *some* of the values.

Comment: Could it be to do with the bitmap row order. I'm vaguely recalling something about some bitmaps being top to bottom and others bottom to top.

Comment: If your question is solved, feel free to post your solution as an answer and accept it. This makes searching the site a bit smoother, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

It seems I misunderstood the situation. The file is saved correctly. The error happened when I stretched the image horizontally in Photoshop to make it easier to see. I need to select "nearest neighbor" or the pixels will get corrupted.